# How to show a firestore Collection in an Android ListView using an Adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a simple app where I need to see every document in a specific `FirebaseFirestore` collection in my app.

To make this work, I thought the best solution would be to use a `ListView` with a custom `ArrayAdapter`. And have the Firestore document be cast to a custom java class I made.

My document is set up to have:

(String) title :

(Date) due_date :

(Number) exp :

(String) description :

However, something in my logic seems to not work. Below is my code for this process:

**Missions.java:**

```
public class Missions {

    private String title;
    private Number exp;
    private String date;
    private String description;

    public Missions() {}

    public Missions(String title, Number exp, String date, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.exp = exp;
        this.date = date;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public Number getExp(){
       return exp;
    }
    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
   }

}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      private final String COLLECTION_KEY = "missions";

      //Views
      private TextView mHeaderView;
      private ListView mMissionListView;

      //Firebase
      private FirebaseFirestore db;

      //Adapter
      private MissionsAdapter mMissionAdapter;
      private ArrayList<Missions> mMissionsList;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        /*
         * My code here deals with authentication
         *
         */
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         mHeaderView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.missionHeader);
         mMissionsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.missionList);

         mHeaderView.setText("Available Missions"));

    //get Database
         db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    //Set up the ArrayList
         mMissionsList = new ArrayList<Missions>();
    //set the Adapter
        mMissionAdapter = new MissionsAdapter(this, mMissionsList);

        mMissionListView.setAdapter(mMissionAdapter);

        db.collection(COLLECTION_KEY).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){

                                    Log.d("MissionActivity", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());

                                    Missions miss = document.toObject(Missions.class);
                                    mMissionsList.add(miss);

                                }

                            }
                            else {
                                Log.d("MissionActivity", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                            }
                        }
                    });
        //add the whole Arraylist of MIssions to the adapter
        mMissionAdapter.addAll(mMissionsList);
      }
    }
```

**MissionsAdapter.java**

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.List;



    public class MissionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Missions> {
        public MissionsAdapter(Context context, List<Missions> object){
            super(context,0, object);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView =  ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_mission,parent,false);
            }

            TextView titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mission_title);
            TextView expTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mission_exp);
            TextView dateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mission_date);
            TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mission_description);

            Missions mission = getItem(position);

            titleTextView.setText(mission.getTitle());
            expTextView.setText(mission.getExp().toString());
            dateTextView.setText(mission.getDate());
            descriptionTextView.setText(mission.getDescription());


            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

**item_missions.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mission_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:hint="There will be a title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mission_exp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearance"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:hint="There will be exp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mission_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearance"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:hint="There will be a date"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mission_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearance"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:hint="There will be a description"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/missionHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Edit/Create mission"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            />


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/missionList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Any comment would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. The problem in your code is that you are trying to populate the adapter with a list that is empty and this is because by the time you are doing this, you haven't finished getting the data from the database. Note that the `onComplete()` method has an asynchronous behaviour. To solve this, please use the following code:

```
db.collection(COLLECTION_KEY).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        List<Missions> mMissionsList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Missions miss = document.toObject(Missions.class);
                mMissionsList.add(miss);
            }
            ListView mMissionsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.missionList);
            MissionsAdapter mMissionAdapter = new MissionsAdapter(this, mMissionsList);
            mMissionsListView.setAdapter(mMissionAdapter);
        } else {
            Log.d("MissionActivity", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, I have declared and used the adapter inside this method.

Comment: Thank you so much that was the solution I needed.
I am still getting a  null object on the date, but I am pretty sure I can get that solved eventually. Thanks again

Comment: So working more on this, I was wondering how I could click on one of the missions shown in the list view and have that open an editing activity with the existing data filled. I thought i could use the setOnClickListener but im  not sure how to pass the selected mission to the next activity, any idea?

Comment: Yes, you can use `setOnClickListener` and inside the onClick method just use: getItem(position) method. If you cannot solve this new challenge, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. Cheers!

Comment: what is QueryDocumentSnapshot. It's showing not resolved?

Comment: @Sandeep [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot) it's a class. Try to use `DocumentSnapshot` instead of `QueryDocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: already done, can you tell me why it gives me `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference`. 
When I use same code inside `addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>()`.

Comment: There might be many reasons for that. So I recommend you post another question so me or other users can help you.